# Change visibilty to richboxtext inlines

Tags: windows-phone-7, visibility, paragraph

Hi I have noticed that Microsoft did not include a visibility property to their paragraph object,
So I want to create one of my own.
Any suggestions of how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the class hierarchy for `Paragraph` you will see why it does not support visibility:

```
System.Object
  System.Windows.DependencyObject
    System.Windows.Documents.TextElement
      System.Windows.Documents.Block
        System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph
```

It does not inherit from `UIElement` or `FrameworkElement`. `Paragraph`, and the other Block elements are lightweight model objects that are used by the `RichTextBox` to render the content, they do not get added to the visual tree like other elements you would typically use within XAML.

For this reason you are not going to be able to create your own visibility property! The only option is to remove the hidden paragraph so that the control re-renders.

Comment: So i guess if I do want that functionality I'll have to build a richTextBox class by my self